# Only Half Records Deletes - Using While Loop (VBA)

Tags: vba, excel, while-loop, excel-2007

So, only half the records which are searched for is getting deleted. PFB the code snippet. Ex: 32 instances of CityName exist. Only 16 gets deleted.

```
i As Long, lngEndRowInv As Long
Set wsh = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet    
i = 1
lngEndRowInv = wsh.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
While i <= lngEndRowInv
If Cells(i, "A") = "CityName" Then
Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
End If
i = i + 1
Wend
```

Does this have to do with the reverse approach? Any help or direction is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because if you delete row 2, then what was previously row 3 is now row 2.  So you need to offset your references every time you delete a row

```
If Cells(i, "A") = "CityName" Then
    Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
    i = i -1
    lngEndRowInv = lngEndRowInv -1
End If
```

Comment: No worries.  I was assuming you were just showing a simplified version of your script.  because a quicker way would be...
`wsh.Range(wsh.Cells(1, 1), wsh.Cells(lngEndRowInv, 1)).Rows.Delete`

Comment: Or you just loop backwards.  Instead of i = 1 to rowcount do i = rowcount to 1 step -1.